# Telegram chat format is wrong

Tags: 18.04, telegram

I recently installed Telegram in Ubuntu 18.04.
But the chat format is not what it should look like. As you can see that my chats should be at the right side:
[image: As you can see that my chats should be at the right side]
Any solutions?

Comment: There should be an option in settings like "Adaptive layout for wide screens". Can you try toggling it?

Answer (score 1):

you should actually resize the left pane and make it big enough so it moves your chats to the right

see screenshots below:

[image: When chats are left]]
[image: When chats are right]